# Could not find trained model in model_dir

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been going through Google's Machine Learning Crash Course, and am at the "First steps with TensorFlow" section. I wanted to run the examples on my machine, and keep getting an error that says:

```
ValueError: Could not find trained model in model_dir: C:\Users\Username\AppData
\Local\Temp\tmpowu7j37s.
```

The folder at the end is different every time I run the script. So it's creating a directory for model_dir, but then puts nothing there, or puts my model there and it is deleted by the time the `predict()` method is called. 
If I try to define model_dir in the estimator.LinearRegressor init method and set the checkpoint_path of the `predict()` method to the same directory, it tells me access is denied no matter where I point, in C or to C:\Users, etc. 
I should also mention I am executing inside an Anaconda environment.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import math

from IPython import display
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import gridspec
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.data import Dataset

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
pd.options.display.max_rows = 10
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.1f}'.format

#LOAD Dataset
california_housing_dataframe = pd.read_csv("california_housing_train.csv", sep=",")

#Randomize data (to avoid ordering bias) and div a clumn by 1000 to get to a learning rate we usually work with
california_housing_dataframe = california_housing_dataframe.reindex(
    np.random.permutation(california_housing_dataframe.index))
california_housing_dataframe["median_house_value"] /= 1000.0
print(california_housing_dataframe) #print top and botton 5 rows (see max rows 10 above)

#examine data briefly
print(california_housing_dataframe.describe())
#________________________________________________________________________________________
# Define the input feature: total_rooms.
my_feature = california_housing_dataframe[["total_rooms"]]

# Configure a numeric feature column for total_rooms.
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("total_rooms")]

# Define the label.
targets = california_housing_dataframe["median_house_value"]

#__________________________________________________________________________________________

# Use gradient descent as the optimizer for training the model.
my_optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0000001)
my_optimizer = tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(my_optimizer, 5.0)

# Configure the linear regression model with our feature columns and optimizer.
# Set a learning rate of 0.0000001 for Gradient Descent.
linear_regressor = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    optimizer=my_optimizer
)

#______________________________________________________________________________________________

def my_input_fn(features, targets, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None):
    """Trains a linear regression model of one feature.

    Args:
      features: pandas DataFrame of features
      targets: pandas DataFrame of targets
      batch_size: Size of batches to be passed to the model
      shuffle: True or False. Whether to shuffle the data.
      num_epochs: Number of epochs for which data should be repeated. None = repeat indefinitely
    Returns:
      Tuple of (features, labels) for next data batch
    """

    # Convert pandas data into a dict of np arrays.
    features = {key:np.array(value) for key,value in dict(features).items()}                                           

    # Construct a dataset, and configure batching/repeating
    ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features,targets)) # warning: 2GB limit
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)

    # Shuffle the data, if specified
    if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)

    # Return the next batch of data
    features, labels = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return features, labels

    #_______________________________________________________________________________________________

    _ = linear_regressor.train(
    input_fn = lambda:my_input_fn(my_feature, targets),
    steps=100
)

    #__________________________________________________________________________________________________

print(linear_regressor.model_dir)

# Create an input function for predictions.
# Note: Since we're making just one prediction for each example, we don't 
# need to repeat or shuffle the data here.
prediction_input_fn =lambda: my_input_fn(my_feature, targets, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)

# Call predict() on the linear_regressor to make predictions.
predictions = linear_regressor.predict(input_fn = prediction_input_fn
  )

# Format predictions as a NumPy array, so we can calculate error metrics.
predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in predictions])
```

Full traceback:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: C:\Users\Username\
AppData\Local\Temp\tmpowu7j37s
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpowu7j37s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fstf.py", line 104, in <module>
    predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in predictions])
  File "fstf.py", line 104, in <listcomp>
    predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in predictions])
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-pac
kages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 471, in predict
    self._model_dir))
ValueError: Could not find trained model in model_dir: C:\Users\Username\AppData
\Local\Temp\tmpowu7j37s.
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't specify a parameter for the `LinearRegressor`,so your trained model is saved in the system temporary directory and deleted/cleaned by the system when your program was completed.

So you should specify a `model_dir` parameter for `LinearRegressor`.
The `__init__` function of `LinearRegressor` is that:

```
__init__(
    feature_columns,
    model_dir=None,
    weight_column_name=None,
    optimizer=None,
    gradient_clip_norm=None,
    enable_centered_bias=False,
    label_dimension=1,
    _joint_weights=False,
    config=None,
    feature_engineering_fn=None
)
```

You can read the doc [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/LinearRegressor#model_dir)

In terms of your code, you should change these code

```
linear_regressor = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    optimizer=my_optimizer
)
```

to

```
linear_regressor = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    optimizer=my_optimizer,
    model_dir="./your_own_model_dir"
)
```

Your program will run successfully, Good Luck！！

Answer (score 0):

i also meet the problem,and i solve that by add these codes:

```html
linear_regressor.train(
    input_fn = lambda:my_input_fn(my_feature, targets),
    steps=100
)
```

because you miss the **Step 5: Train the Model**

Answer (score 0):

you should set eval_steps is 1 or smaller,
and set eval_batch_size is all eval data or more bigger.
if it will evaluate much steps,
for cheackpoint life circle, it only keep 5 last .ckpt for default(you can customize).
and the next step's batch can't to evaluate.
and it will raise a error:
ValueError: Could not find trained model in model_dir: {your_model_dir}.
more detail: 
- https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/RunConfig
- https://github.com/colinwke/wide_deep_demo